# django rest frame work tutorial 4 serializer concept

Tags: django-rest-framework

I finished tutorial 1-4 at http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions.html and got the code run.

However, I am not fully understand the explanation around:

```
owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
```

I am confused by which field refering to which field.

1.For example, there is an owner field defined in Snippet class in models.py. After looking it up at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey, it says `ForeignKey()` returns a class. Does it return the `auth.User` class?

2.If it does, what "owner" does the

```
owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
```

refer to? I do not found owner in the import part of `serializers.py`.

3.What does `serializers.Field(source='owner.username')` returns? Does it return the username in the auth.User?

4.Should we add the corresponding field in a serializer class if the corresponding model has a field reference to another table?

Answer (score 0):

source = 'owner.username' will translate to 'user.username' since owner is nothing but FK-User.

Please note that 'owner' on the left side of field is not important here, in your case. i.e, you can still add custom fields like,

```
xyz = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
```